# PyTorch is giving me a different value for a scalar

Tags: floating-point, pytorch, tensor

When I create a tensor from float using PyTorch, then cast it back to a float, it produces a different result. Why is this, and how can I fix it to return the same value?

```
num = 0.9
float(torch.tensor(num))
```

Output:

```
0.8999999761581421
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a floating-point "issue" and you read more about how Python 3 handles those [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Essentially, not even `num` is actually storing 0.9. Anyway, the print issue in your case comes from the fact that `num` is actually double-precision and `torch.tensor` uses single-precision by default. If you try:

```py
num = 0.9
float(torch.tensor(num, dtype=torch.float64))
```

you'll get `0.9`.